# Illegal modifier for parameter [variable]; only final is permitted

Tags: java

I am trying to write a method that gets a string of numbers "123188"

then returns an `int[]` which contains digits.

that what I've got so far :

```
public int[] stringToDig(String a)
{
  char [] ch1 = a.toCharArray();
  int [] conv = new int [ch1.length];

  for (int i=0 ; i<ch1.length ; i++)
      conv[i] = Character.getNumericValue(ch1[i]);

  return conv; 
}
```

and I got that

> Multiple markers at this line:
>
> - Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
> - Syntax error on token ")", ; expected
> - Illegal modifier for parameter stringToDig; only final is 
>      permitted

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: This code looks like it works to me

Comment: Sorry ,I just edited the question  :)

Comment: @iShaalan did you put this method inside of another method?

Comment: yes . the main method in my class

Comment: @iShaalan That's why then. You can't put methods inside methods (except kind of a bit in special cases).

Comment: Okay . I got the mistake thank you all  @Cruncher

Comment: @chancea  What is it friend ? :)

Comment: To be fair, I don't think this question deserves down votes! Can the down voters explain?

Comment: @jahroy Um http://www.google.com/trends/explore#q=method%20inside%20method&cmpt=q

Comment: `Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.`

What of this was violated?

Comment: @Cruncher - Really??!  The OP doesn't understand that you can't put a method inside a method and you're asking why people voted to close?  The purpose of upvoting, downvoting, and closing questions is to make this site more useful, not to improve Cruncher's reputation.  You've already got 12% of your reputation from this one question (including 10 points from my upvote).

Comment: @Cruncher - That's a good edit to the title, so I removed my downvote.

Comment: @jahroy FYI, this question is now the top google hit for "Illegal modifier for parameter foo; only final is permitted". Sounds pretty useful to me. I still can't believe this was closed. What are we telling people when they come with legitimate questions and close it on them? This is off-topic anyway and I'll probably delete this comment, I just felt a rant was imminent.

Comment: @Cruncher - I don't make the rules for upvoting and downvoting, I just follow them. It's pretty obvious why this would rise to the top of the google results, given the title is a compiler error message... When you edited the title, this _became_ a useful question (only because of your title and your answer).  I voted to close before you edited it.  I'm sorry my initial vote to close was so upsetting to you, but it would have happened anyways. 4 people agreed within a half-hour...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't put methods inside of other methods in Java.

Structure your program like this:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] digits = stringToDig("54235");
    }

    public int[] stringToDig(String a)
    {
        char [] ch1 = a.toCharArray();
        int [] conv = new int [ch1.length];

        for (int i=0 ; i<ch1.length ; i++)
            conv[i] = Character.getNumericValue(ch1[i]);

        return conv; 
    }
}
```

Comment: The fact that you were able to recognize the problem by just the error. +1

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public int[] stringToDig(String a) {

  char[] ch1 = a.toCharArray();
  int[] conv = new int[ch1.length];

  for (int i = 0; i < ch1.length; i++)
    conv[i] = Character.digit(ch1[i], 10); // here's the difference

  return conv; 

}
```

The preferred method for converting a character digit to the corresponding `int` value is by using the [`digit()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#digit%28int,%20int%29) method. Here's another option, although it's a bit of a hack and will only work for digits in base 10 (unlike using `digits()`, which works for other bases):

```
conv[i] = ch1[i] - '0';
```

Besides that, @Cruncher is right - the errors shown seem to indicate that you forgot to put the method *inside* a class! follow his advice.

Comment: From your answer, a question arose. Why is digit the preferred method? What problems would arise from using getNumericValue? Thank you for your time

Comment: Not really "problems", but digit() gives you more control over the conversion in case the character is in a base different than 10

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me:

```
public int[] stringToDig(String a) {
    char[] chars = a.toCharArray();
    int[] ints = new int[chars.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++)
        ints[i] = chars[i] - 48;

    return ints;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> import java.util.Arrays;
>
> public class NewClass {
>
> ```
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stringToDig("123456789")));
> }
>
> public static int[] stringToDig(String a) {
>     int [] c = new int[a.length()];
>     for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
>         c[i] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(a.charAt(i)));
>     }
>     return c;
> }
> ```
>
> }